# Страничные запросы в JPA

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

вывожу данные из базы подобным образом:

```
  @GetMapping()
public List<DAOUser> findAll(){
   return userRepository.findAll();
}
```

Как мне вывести только 10 пользоватлей, начиная с 5й записи?

Comment: А вам насколько абстрактно надо это сделать? Я знаю способ через `nativeQuery` для `postgresql`. Но это надо будет писать SQL под конкретную БД.

Comment: Можете отобрать Top15 в сервисе первые 5 удалить. Просто постановка какая-то странная. может этим 5-и какой нибудь признак задать и тогда по нему фильтровать, а то сегодня 5 завтра уже 10...

Comment: Я нашел то, что вы ищете вот [ответ со stackoverlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44475290/how-to-define-where-to-start-retrieving-data-with-spring-data-pageable-request)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я так понимаю вопрос из области пагинации. Так вот есть два стула:

1. Программная пагинация
2. Пагинация на уровне базы

В первом случае вы достаете из базы все данные и с помощью упорядоченных коллекций в отдельном методе извлекаете нужные вам строки. Данный способ можно использовать при относительно небольшом кол-ве записей, так как большое кол-во вхождений в коллекцию приведет к замусориванию памяти. Реализуется это как правило через обертку для коллекции, сублист или стрим в зависимости от того как вы хотите видеть свой метод.

Второй случай предполагает что у вас к базе будут идти запросы только N нужных вам строк, что конечно перенесет нагрузку на уровень БД. Однако в этом случае требуется написание запросов под конкретную БД. Если вы используете Spring Data то вы можете воспользоваться данным [примером](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-pagination-sorting).

Comment: Второе мне подходит. Буду пробовать. Спасибо

Comment: Всё получилось. Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Для страничного запроса следует добавить специальный метод в твой репозиторий, где есть параметр с типом [Pageable](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Pageable.html). Этот метод должен возвращать объект с типом [Page](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Page.html). К примеру это будет выглядеть так:

```java
interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<DAOUser, Long> {
    Page<DAOUser> findAll(Pageable);
}
```

Вызов будет примерно такой:

```java
PageRequest pageRequest = PageRequest.of(page, size);
Page<DAOUser> result = userRepository.findAll(pageRequest);
```

Конкретно для указанного случая уже реализован специальный интерфейс [PagingAndSortingRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/PagingAndSortingRepository.html), где есть данный метод.

Comment: Уже сделал данным спобом. Спасибо :)